# How to extract numerator and denominator from polynomial without evaluating?

Tags: sympy

I have the following expression

```
A=Symbol('A')
x=Symbol('x')
B=Symbol('B')
C=Symbol('C')
D=Symbol('D')
expression=((A**x-B-C)/(D-1))*(D-1)
n,d=fraction(expression)
```

I am getting following result:

```
n=A**x-B-C
d=1
```

My expected result is

```
n=(A**x-B-C)*(D-1)
d=(D-1)
```

Is there way in sympy or need to write customize function to handle that

Comment: `expression`  is `(A**x-B-C)`, since Sympy canceled the `D-1` term. As far as I know there's no easy way to prevent the canceling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `UnevaluatedExpr()` to prevent the expression from being evaluated.

```
from sympy import symbols, fraction, UnevaluatedExpr

A,x,B,C,D = symbols('A x B C D')

expression = (A**x-B-C)/(D-1)*UnevaluatedExpr(D-1)
n,d = fraction(expression)
print(n)
print(d)
```

This returns

```
(A**x - B - C)*(D - 1)
D - 1
```

See the Sympy [Advanced Expression Manipulation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation) doc page for more details.